# How does the docky show desktop Docklet work

Tags: gnome, docky

Docky has the feature of tiling/cascading the desktop. I'd like to know what it taps into to acheive this, and if I could get similar functionality in Unity without docky

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit, I'm also curious to know but there is a package that control the behaviour without needing to get under the bonnet.

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

From there you can run:

```
wmctrl -k on  # hides the desktop
wmctrl -k off # restores
```

Here's a script for toggling (Credit to [Jeff.Smith on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10083165&postcount=2)):

```
#!/bin/sh
if wmctrl -m | grep "mode: ON"; then
    exec wmctrl -k off
else
    exec wmctrl -k on
fi
```

Save that somewhere, `chmod +x` it and create a launcher for it and you're done.